# java constructor error (cannot pass int to the constructor)

Tags: java, methods, constructor, integer, stack

hi I'm new to java and I've been trying to pass an int form main method to a constructor in another class but there is some kind of error occurring. I can't understand what i did wrong.

class with the main method :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class _01 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your : ");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        int size = name.length();

        //System.out.println(size);


        _02 process = new _02(size);

    }

}
```

class that has the constructor:

```
public class _02 {

    int maxsize;
    int top;
    String arrayStack[];

    public void _02(int size) {

        maxsize = size;
        arrayStack = new String[maxsize];
        top = -1;
    }

    public void push(String... letters) {

        arrayStack[++top] = letters;

    }

    public String pop() {

        return arrayStack[top--];


    }
}
```

error message i'm getting :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:      The constructor _02(int) is undefined
>
> at _01.main(_01.java:16)

Comment: And it appears that everyone is on the ball today ... ;-) 4 answers and a comment within a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are using `void`. Java thinks those are methods, not constructors. First of all stop giving your classes awful names. And then do this:

```
public class Whatever {
   private Integer size;
   public Whatever(Integer size) {
      this.size = size;
      System.out.println("I am a constructor");
   };
};
```

**Example**

```
public class Article {
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private String author;
    private DateTime publishDate;

    public Article(String title, String content, String author, DateTime publishDate) {
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
        this.author = author;
        this.publishDate = publishDate;
    };

};
```

Assume we are working together on a newspaper project. If I read your code and see `_01`, it means nothing to me. If instead I see `Article`, with `title`, `content`, etc. I can immediately understand what you wrote and use it as I please.

If you come back to your own code two weeks later, you won't have a clue what you meant by `_01`. As many developers, you won't remember. There's even a joke about it, done through a comment. It goes like this:

```
/**
 * At the time of this writing, only God and I knew what I was doing.
 * Now, only God knows.
 * /
```

**Remeber, code is easy to write but very hard to read.**

Comment: thanks man! i have to name classes that way because my teacher wants us to follow same format :/

Comment: can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

A constructor is a method without return type, so your constructor declaration should be:

```
public _02(int size)
```

A good practice will be to use follow java style guide, using names with capitalize letrer as class names, for example `Two`

Answer (score 0):

A constructor doesn't have a return type. So remove `void` from `public void _02(int size)` if you want to use it as a constructor.

Your class naming is a little odd though...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 'void' from public void _02(int size) { ... }